# implementing "filtering method" with java, jsf,mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, arraylist

I have to implement an online delivery service with java and JSF for studying.
i use a mysql database to store the meals.
the user sees the menu as a dataTable and outputTexts that contains a ListDataModel. The datamodel contains an array from the mysql database. my idea was the user has to write a quantity to inputText for each meal he wants. when clicking next page, all rows with a quantity above 0 shall be kept in another array to display and use for "billing".I already tried some different ways but didnt figured it out yet..
Would be great if anybody may help, this is my current code:

```
public class Product {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int price;
    private int productNr;
    private String productName;
    private String desc;
    private int qty = 0;
    
    public Product() {
        
    }
    
    public Product(int productNr, int price, String productName, String desc, int qty) {
        this.productNr = productNr;
        this.price = price;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.qty = qty;
    }
....getter & setter
}
```

```
public class MbMenu {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private final String CLASSNAME = getClass().getName();


    private ListDataModel<Product[]> menu = null;
    private ListDataModel<OrderItem[]> order = null;
    private ArrayList<Product> allProduct = new ArrayList<Product>();
    private ArrayList<Product> orderElements = new ArrayList<Product>();

    private Util util = new Util();

    private Connection con = null;
    private Statement stm = null;
    private ResultSet rs = null;



    public MbMenu() {

        out.println("MbMenu.<init>...\n" + (new Date()).toString());
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        out.println("@PostConstruct.MbMenu");
    }
    
    public ListDataModel<Product[]> getMenu() {
        getAll();

        if (menu == null)
            menu = new ListDataModel(allProduct);

        return menu;
    }

    public void setMenu(ListDataModel<Product[]> menu) {
        this.menu = menu;
    }
    
    public ListDataModel<OrderItem[]> getOrder() {
        
        if (order == null)
            order = new ListDataModel(orderElements);

        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(ListDataModel<OrderItem[]> order) {
        this.order = order;
    }


    public ArrayList<Product> getAll() {

        final String MNAME = "getAll()";
        util.log(CLASSNAME + "." + MNAME + "...");

        util.log("ArrayList<Product> neu aufbauen...");

        allProduct.clear();

        if (util != null)
            con = util.getCon();
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                Statement stm = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                checkWarning(stm.getWarnings());

                rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT nummer, name, beschreibung, preis, menge " + "FROM gerichte ORDER BY nummer");

                while (rs.next()) {
                    // ArrayList aus ResultSet aufbauen:
                    Product p = new Product();

                    p.setProductNr(rs.getInt(1));
                    p.setProductName(rs.getString(2));
                    p.setDesc(rs.getString(3));
                    p.setPrice(rs.getInt(4));
                    p.setQty(rs.getInt(5));

                    allProduct.add(p);
                }

                util.log("Anzahl Produkte in ArrayList: " + allProduct.size());
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "SQLException", ex.getLocalizedMessage()));
                while (ex != null) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    ex = ex.getNextException();
                }
            }

        }

        util.log("..." + CLASSNAME + "." + MNAME);
        return allProduct;
    }
    public ArrayList<Product> makeOrder(){

    ***this method is supposed to "filter" only entrys with quantites above 0***

    }
}
```

```
datatables and button in xhtml file:


<ui:define name="content">

            <h:form>

                <h:dataTable value="#{mbMenu.menu}" var="product">

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name = "header" >Nr</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{product.productNr} &#160;" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                    <f:facet name = "header" >Gericht</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{product.productName} &#160;" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                    <f:facet name = "header" >Beschreibung</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{product.desc} &#160;" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                    <f:facet name = "header" >Preis</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{product.price}&#160;" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                    <f:facet name = "header" >Anzahl</f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value="#{product.qty}" size ="2"/>
                    </h:column>

                </h:dataTable>

                <h:commandButton value="Bestellübersicht"
                    action="client_warenkorb.xhtml"
                    actionListener = "#{mbMenu.makeOrder}" />
            </h:form>

        </ui:define>
```

[user view menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBRZJ.png)